# Is there a "soft way" for shutting down processes in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, application-shutdown

In PowerShell, if you want to stop a process, you use

```
Get-Process process | Stop-Process
```

Is there a way to do this gracefully, so that if needed, one may clean up e.g. that open files can be saved?

Answer (score 0):

*Actually I was writing the question when I decided to review the documentation again and found an answer. I'm posting it anyway, just in case it might help somebody.*

To do this pass the `Confirm` and `PassThru` arguments to `Stop-Process`. So, the code will look like this:

```
Get-Process -Name "process" | Stop-Process -Confirm -PassThru
```

Comment: This will ask for confirmation in PowerShell, but if you say "yes", it still ends the process quite rudely. `$_.CloseMainWindow()` is a gentler way of asking processes with a GUI to stop, as it will prompt the user to save files. This has no effect on processes that have no interface, of course, and you may want to kill the process rudely anyway if the graceful close takes too long.

Comment: Yes this is great. Could you post as an answer?